# Python - Why is my for loop skipping lines and not reaching the end of the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, readline

I'm writing a simple function that takes the path of a text file and returns the number of lines contained in that file.

I've made sure to set the file pointer to the beginning using file.seek(0).

```
def get_number_lines(file_dir):

    exists = os.path.isfile(file_dir) 
    if (exists):
        print(file_dir)
        line_count = 0
        read_file  = open(file_dir,'r')
        read_file.seek(0)
        for line_num, line in enumerate(read_file.readlines()):
            line_count = line_num
            print(line)
        read_file.close()

        return (line_count + 1)
    else:
        print("ERROR: FILE \"" + file_dir + "\" does not exist.")
        exit()
```

Strangely, when I try calling the function it runs ok but the output is telling me that my file is 3 lines shorter than it actually is. When I print the file lines it appears to be skipping the last 3 lines of the file and I'm not sure why.

Comment: `read_file.seek(0)` is pointless there... opening a file in read mode sets the cursor to the start of the file anyway.

Comment: You don't need to call `seek(0)`, and you should look into using `with` to open files.

Comment: Also, that's the most overcomplicated way I've ever seen someone write `line_count = len(read_file.readlines())`.

Comment: Perhaps 3 of your lines are long and wrap around when printed or displayed, giving the illusion of having more lines than you have. In any event, without a [mcve] your question isn't really answerable.

Comment: Umm... you can just use `sum(1 for line in read_file)` to count the number of lines - you don't need the `.readlines()` (which pulls it into memory) and the +1 afterwards either that way.

Comment: It works fine in my machine. I am running python 3.7

Comment: Also - what are you using to assert that your output is wrong and that it should be 3 more than you're getting?

Comment: @Jon I'm opening the file in gedit (and can see that the last 3 lines are missing).

Comment: @Ddor err... what do you mean by "see that the last 3 lines are missing"? What does `wc filename` show for instance?

Comment: @JonClements I am literally looking at the line numbers in gedit. wc filename gives me the same... it is returning 96 whereas the function is returning 93.

Comment: It is at least possible that you have an ill-formatted windows text file which mixes line feeds and carriage returns in an inconsistent way. Open it in a hex editor if you really want to see what is happening.

Comment: @Ddor on a side note - I'd strongly advise against calling `exit()` (which I'm assuming is `sys.exit()`) inside a function. Let the caller decide whether it's an exit condition or not - raise an exception and let the caller handle it (or not).

Comment: As @John notes - you might want to try opening the file in "universal new line mode" by using `open(filename, 'U')` and see if that affects things.

Comment: @JonClements Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and no luck unfortunately-  still getting the same.

Comment: @JohnColeman Tried opening in a hex editor and there is nothing strange. All standard unix line feeds

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the below code using "with open" instead of read_file.seek.

Personal opinion but it works a lot better for reading .txt files. The function will return the number of lines found in the path given to the function. If it is not a file that exists it will error and exit.

```
def Get_Number_Lines(file_dir):
    exists = os.path.isfile(file_dir) 
    if (exists):
        print(file_dir)
        line_count = 0

        with open(file_dir, 'rb') as fin:

            reader = fin.readlines()

            for line in reader:
                line_count += 1

        return line_count

    else:
        print("ERROR: FILE \"" + file_dir + "\" does not exist.")
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate all the suggestions. So I discovered that I had a file object (in write mode) open prior to calling the get_number_lines() function i.e.

```
write_file = open(outputFileDir,"w+")
    # do stuff
get_number_lines(outputFileDir)
```

I then tried closing the the file prior to calling the function which solved the issue I was having. Out of curiousity I also tried this, which works no problem:

```
write_file = open(outputFileDir,"w+")
    # do stuff
write_file.close()
read_file.open(outputFileDir,"r")
get_number_lines(outputFileDir)
```

I didn't realise having two file objects (one in read, and one in write) could cause this issue.